# Actualizar tabla con el sum de otra tabla

Tags: mysql

Necesito actualizar una tabla con la suma de totales de otra tabla, intento lo siguiente:

```
UPDATE adm_invoice_master
    INNER JOIN
    adm_invoice_detail ON inv_id = idt_invMasterId 
SET 
    inv_subTotal = sum(idt_subTotal),
    inv_total = sum(idt_total)
WHERE
    inv_id = 2532;
```

pero me retorna "Invalid use of group function", como debe quedar la consulta de actualización?

Comment: y que es lo que queres que sume en esos campos? toda la tabla?

Comment: se trata de una tabla master y otra detalle con una relación de uno a muchos, necesito sumar los valores del detalle (idt_subTotal y idt_total) y grabarlos en el master cuando se cumpla la condicion

Comment: Tienes que realizar la suma en algun lado no ? para ello creo que debes realizar una subconsulta.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba realizar el update de la siguiente manera:

```
UPDATE adm_invoice_master AS master
INNER JOIN (SELECT a.idt_invMasterId AS id, sum(a.idt_subTotal) AS subTotal, sum(a.idt_total) AS total
            FROM adm_invoice_detail a
            WHERE a.idt_invMasterId = 2532) AS detail
ON master.inv_id = detail.id
SET master.inv_subTotal = detail.subTotal, master.inv_total = detail.total
WHERE master.inv_id = 2532;
```

Espero te sirva, Saludos.

Comment: Si funciona, gracias... pero si le cambio el operador de la condición.. ejemplo a <2532 ya no funciona

Comment: cuando hablas del cambio del operador, a cual te refieres, al de la consulta o al del update como tal?